# Do I need to worry about my Mutex being garbage collected if I declare it static (WPF)?

Tags: c#

I have been looking at some of the different ways people use mutexes to prevent multiple instances of their programs. One of the concerns with using a mutex in C# seems to be that your mutex can be disposed of by the garbage collector over time.

I'm using a mutex in my WPF project to enforce a single instance of the application as follows:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private string UniqueMutexName = string.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}", ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false)[0]).Value);
    private static Mutex mutex = null;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        bool singleInstance;
        mutex = new Mutex(true, UniqueMutexName, out singleInstance);

        if (!singleInstance)
        {
            NativeMethods.PostMessage((IntPtr)NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST, NativeMethods.WindowsMessage.WM_INSTANCEATTEMPT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            Current.Shutdown();
        }
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Does the fact that I declared the mutex as static prevent it from being disposed of by the garbage collector even though I have to instantiate it within the method, or do I need to do something else? I've seen everything from people wrapping the mutex in a using statement to using a try/finally block to manually dispose of the mutex, but since I'm using WPF and overriding the OnStartup method rather than editing the actual entry point, I can't really take that approach.

Answer (score 1):

If an *object* become eligible for *garbage collection* because it was `static` and instantiated in a method, there would be a lot of crashing applications out there.

Another way to look at this, if you can access it (write code that can target that reference) and has not been set to `null`, then it will be ineligible

> Does the fact that I declared the mutex as static prevent it from
>   being disposed of by the garbage collector

The answer is yes (in any usual sense)

---

**Additional Resources**

[Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)